# Domain and Webhost in two different companies

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, domain, web-hosting

I am planning to migrate from godaddy to another webhosting company but not including my domain registrations. I have two domain names and I am planning to get one free domain name from the webhosting company that I will be relocated.

**My Questions**

1) if the domain registration and the webhost is in a different hosting company how thus it affects the speed of my site, how long my domains will be resolved so that my customers will reach my web host?

2) I am planning to get a multi domain SSL certificate for my two domains, how will the two different providers will affect my ssl certificate installation?.

Note: I will have a dedicated Ip to my new webhost

Comment: Dedicated IP doesn't change anything regarding your questions.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no speed difference normally. You can lower the TTL of your records a few days before moving to make the propagation faster.

2) Godaddy should not have anything to do with it, only the webhost has to install the SSL.

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't change your ns servers for this domains, so speed of resolving names will be the same for your clients.

To clarify: 
To open your site from client-side following things should happen(generaly): dns name should be resolved to ip address(this will be the same), HTTP request should go to this IP address(this step can change because of different routing, rtt and general network), server should answer to this request(this step can change also because of overal performance of server where your new hosting would be).

So it's common practice to have your own ns server for your domain and web-site hosting on some third-party company. This doesn't impact performance.

2) They won't affect. You will buy new certificate and ask your hosting company to install it on web-server. Actually you can even create your own certificate and install it on server.

To clarify: 
When you create your certificate your have CN record there which points to some domain. But certificate issuer doesn't request approve that you are owner of this domain.